# Error when upgraded operating system from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04> do-release-upgrade

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade

**Error when upgraded operating system from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04> do-release-upgrade**

```
Current version:
cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS"
```

**Any body faced this issue ?
Is there a solution to this ?**

```
**do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive**

Send problem report to the developers?

After the problem report has been sent, please fill out the form in the
automatically opened web browser.

What would you like to do? Your options are:
  S: Send report (302.5 KB)
  V: View report
  K: Keep report file for sending later or copying to somewhere else
  I: Cancel and ignore future crashes of this program version
  C: Cancel
Please choose (S/V/K/I/C): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apport-cli", line 386, in <module>
    if not app.run_argv():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/ui.py", line 673, in run_argv
    return self.run_report_bug()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/ui.py", line 511, in run_report_bug
    response = self.ui_present_report_details(allowed_to_report)
  File "/usr/bin/apport-cli", line 213, in ui_present_report_details
    response = dialog.run()
  File "/usr/bin/apport-cli", line 101, in run
    multi_char)
  File "/usr/bin/apport-cli", line 49, in raw_input_char
    saved_attributes = termios.tcgetattr(file)
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

**var log errors**

```
/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log

2021-04-27 15:31:12,436 ERROR No 'ubuntu-minimal' available/downloadable after sources.list rewrite+update
2021-04-27 15:31:12,436 ERROR 'ubuntu-minimal' was not downloadable
2021-04-27 15:31:12,436 ERROR Invalid package information After updating your package information, the essential package 'ubuntu-minimal' could not be located. This may be because you have no official mirrors listed in your software sources, or because of excessive load on the mirror you are using. See /etc/apt/sources.list for the current list of configured software sources.
In the case of an overloaded mirror, you may want to try the upgrade again later. (None)
2021-04-27 15:31:12,448 DEBUG abort called
```

Comment: Your output suggests that your sources were incorrect, or the mirror was overloaded/unavailable. Try running `do-release-upgrade` normally for additional information.

Comment: yes you are right apt.conf and sources.list were incorrect.